# Way to create these kind of "gravitional waves"

Tags: animation

I would like to have this style of waves

[image: this style]

with dynamic paint, but I can't quite get the waves to be large/defined enough. Maybe theres a way of doing this with curves in Geometry Nodes? Is this effect possible? Procedurally is preferred but if it's baked that is also acceptable.

EDIT:
I was inspired by @vklidu's answer using the mesh spirals and did that with a geometry nodes setup.

[image]

And we get this output

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a black and white spiral image from some source you can use a [displacement modifier]. Blurring the image will create the gradient effect.  As you know .. a high density mesh is useful for smooth appearance.  Source of image.  Proportional edit can take an radial mesh .. like the spokes of a wheel and twist them.  Shader nodes can create spirals.  Perhaps there are free Spiral patterns on the glitchernet.

Comment: Use may also use Curve Modifier on the spirals curves to get tubular spirals as depicted in your moving image. Perhaps you like the fact that there is no decreasing thickness at the center of the spiral.  This could also be the source of an image in the step above.

Comment: Suggestion .. show your work with displacement modifier and spiral image as a start, that might be a good experience for you.  Someone else might do it for you below.

Comment: You might also use the radial mesh from the top of a sphere or similar, extrude some elevation, and proportional edit the spiral rotation from the center.

Comment: @TheJeran ... Hey - GN has already Spiral primitive? My living in a box :) Thanks ...  I edited this part of my answer if you don't mind :) BTW you can post regular Answer and mark it as accepted. BTW2 I didn't check the rest your node tree, but Two Spheres part could be simplified (see my edit).

Comment: @vklidu Yea, that's simpler. I forgot about instancing and had a one track mind on transferring attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @TheJeran's edit - GN has already spiral primitive :) so just join with rotated instance ...

[image]
[image]

... to be seen by *Geometry Proximity* node add *Curve to Mesh* node
and continue with this node-tree ...

[image]
[image]

- The violet field of Z rotation is driver expression to animate rotation without keyframes ... done just by clicking into the field and type `#frame*0.2` or some similar value.
- For low-res grid like this you can add *Set Smooth* node.

Edit: Speaking to your node-tree with two Spheres - you can simplified tree ...

[image]
[image]

Simple grid shader based on **Brick** texture node ...

[image]
[image]
To be assigned the final object you would have to add *Set Material* node at the end of GeoNodes tree.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is not with *Dynamic Paint* and it won't give exactly the same but you could try with *Shrinkwrap*:

Create this object with 2 curve spirals that you convert to mesh and parent to an empty, make the spiral object invisible:

[image]

Then create a plane, subdivide, give it these 3 modifiers: *Subdivision Surface, Shrinkwrap* (with the spiral object as *Target* and *Wrap Method > Project*), and *Corrective Smooth*:

[image]

Here is what it gives when you rotate the empy:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's geonodes solution:

[image]

Shader:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: last minute errata, rather than ${x\over{1\overτ}}$ you could do $xτ$ (one multiply node instead of two divide nodes)…

Answer (score 4):

Here i the node setup for a displacement modifier producing the desired shape.
It relies on a cartesian to cylindrical coordinates transformation and then a cosine function.

You can then animate it with a #frame driver, but I was too lazy to do it :P

Or you can use the same nodes with blobs placed on a mesh with geonodes.

[image]

If the ripples decrease in intensity with distance, a negative exponential can be added:

[image]